# Bash MinGW ignoring Ctrl+O key combination

Tags: windows-7, bash, mingw

In Bash MinGW on Windows 7, I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> to perform a history search backward. 
However, I can't get this work -- i.e., this line in my `~/.inputrc` does nothing (although it does work on a unix system I have access to):

```
"\C-o": history-search-backward
```

Using the <kbd>Up</kbd> key is ok, i.e. this works:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
```

I know that the terminal application (Console2) is not capturing the <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd>, since I can map <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> to various things in terminal vim (launched from MinGW bash in Console2).

Anyone know why <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> is being ignored in Bash MinGW?

Comment: I'll bet `Ctrl-S` and `Ctrl-Q` don't work either. Most likely that these characters are being used for flow control.  When vim runs, it turns this off, but bash does not.  If you were running on Unix, you'd be able to use `stty` to disable this, but I haven't figured out how to disable this in Windows.  BTW there doesn't seem to be a problem with `Ctrl-P`.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds right. I found this answer on the Apple site where you can use `stty discard undef` to make Ctrl+O work in mac terminal, but it doesn't work on Windows. (http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/ctrl-o-behavior-in-terminal-app). And you were right about Ctrl-P working, so I edited the question title. And sorry I can't vote up your comment, insufficient rep.